# Where is the best place to put a feedback button on mobile site?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, human-interface-guideline

We're placing a feedback button on our mobile site (currently it's in beta). The button should be easily noticeable, easily accessible, and yet not be too distracting or cover up too much of the screen.

Any ideas for how best to manage this? Should be pop-up following user icons? Should it be always present on the screen?  Any ideas for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "be pop-up following user icons". I thought you were questioning only about the presence of a button. Are you asking for  flow or placement?

Comment: Who edited my question? I didn't write that line and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question was edited because it was very brief and didn't have any detail. You're welcome to edit it again yourself, but if this edit isn't relevant then please amend it yourself to include more detail.

Comment: I think you will need to add a wireframe or sketch of your site.  Asking where to put a feedback button without showing us what the application looks like is similar to asking what handle to use for a door without explaining what whether it's a commercial, residential, wood, steel, sliding, or swinging door....the answer depends mostly on the overall context it's placed in.

Answer (score 1):

If this element is important and represents a need for you, then it should be always present.

Now, I have no idea what your app is about, but you could consider these choices on top of the above:

- **Ask for feedback after action is completed**
  Let's say your app performs X action, or you have a video or whatever. Then you could end that action with a CTA requesting feedback
- **Ask for feedback after certain content is reached**
  In this case, you want people to read some content, so when the viewport hits the bottom of that content, you can pop or slide a dialog requesting for feedback
- **Make feedback part of the experience**
  In this case, you can let the users know the beta will request some feedback. This is a very useful scenario because you can request feedback "on the fly" and let people add feedback on specific instances (we use this A LOT, as a matter of fact is our main testing tool)

Again, I have no idea what your app is about, but hope these ideas are of help for you

Answer (score 0):

I would put some label indicating that the site is in beta near the site title. Clicking on this button could be a good way to give feedback. If you want a separate feedback button, near the top of the site would make sense. This would be especially effective if it was a "sticky" button, i.e. it stays at the top of the screen even when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to put the feedback (theoretically) is after the user has had a chance to complete the goal/task which you want feedback about. So in most cases this would not be near the top for new users, because it would be difficult to provide feedback about the site when they haven't had a chance to experience/explore it yet. On desktop websites the trend is to put them on the bottom right hand side, but on a mobile device this probably needs to be somewhere that is accessible by the thumb yet not blocking any direct actions or accidental contact/touch. If you take all this into consideration with the rest of the content for your website you should be able to come up with the right position for it.